# List of hospital names with their abbreviations

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

I am looking for a dataset containing:

- hospital names: either full names or abbreviations (ideally, both)

Optionally:

- location of the hospital (e.g., in which state)
- size of the hospital (e.g., number of beds, or surface)

I mostly interested in the United States.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_hospitals_in_the_United_States is incomplete and doesn't contain hospital name abbreviations.

Comment: @albert Thanks, I'll look at it. At some point I thought I could get it from Wikidata, but their API doesn't seem so polish. Also data would most likely be incomplete.

Comment: this could be helpful, but its only medicaid registered facilities, and no abbreviations. however i'm guessing if you track down the facility ids to a more definitive file, the abbr may be there. also, could be completely useless for you https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Hospital-General-Information/xubh-q36u

Answer (score 2):

maybe the hospital file within the medicare cost reports?

https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Downloadable-Public-Use-Files/Cost-Reports/Cost-Reports-by-Fiscal-Year-Items/HOSPITAL10-DL-2015.html?DLPage=1&DLEntries=10&DLSort=0&DLSortDir=descending